# How to correct use $X in jasper??. Problem with parameters and IN clause in JSS

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a report made with Jaspersoft Studio and in the dataset query I need to use an IN clause, for that I am using the expression `"$X{IN ..."`

**Question # 1: What is the correct type to use for the parameter?**
I'm using the following format:
[image]

**Question # 2: How do I test in the preview?**
Parameters screen:

[image]

To help, follow the excerpt of where with the parameter being used:

`"...Where (($X{IN, db.empresa, paramIdEmpresa}) OR $ P!{ParamIdEmpresa} IS NULL) and (db_view ... "`

**Error that appears in the preview with the above parameters:**

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error executing SQL statement
for: unit1. at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportController.fillReport
(ReportController.java:551) at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportController.access
 (BaseFillHandle.java:135) at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
 Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at
 or near "["   Position: 199 at
 org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse
 (QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440) at
 org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults
```

Comment: `$ X {IN, db.empresa, paramIdEmpresa}`  - This is invlalid syntax. The right one is `$X{IN, db.empresa, paramIdEmpresa}` where db.empresa has numeric type

Comment: :) , it was a mistake by the translator ... he put these spaces there. I already corrected it, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

the problem was in the query and not in jasper...

the correct query is:

```
where 
    (($X{IN,db.idempresa, paramIdEmpresa}) OR db.idempresa IS NULL )
```

thanks to GP...

Answer (score 0):

The best possible way to solve it is simple:

1. create a parameter called `$P!{paramWhere}.` of your application
2. pass the complete `where` clause with this parameter, e.g. `"id = 200"`

In your query inside `jasper`, you put it like this: `"... select * from <anywhere> where $P!{paramWhere} ..."` and it will magically work.

Comment: "id=200" is using literals instead of bind variables. This syntax requires extra-parsing time and uses a "slot" in the cache everytime the value 200 changes. You should avoid writing queries like this.